# What is the best way to maintain session information in Angular App during page refresh

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, session, cookies

Joomla is the backend of the application. Am receiving the Session ID after successful login through an ajax call.

1. what is the best way to store that information in the Angular App?
2. what is the best method (cookies or something else) to send session data on subsequent ajax calls?

Comment: You can use session storage to save the info on angular side. Easy to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Best way to store your information in Angular App is either $rootScope or $localStorage.

2) You can use Http Interceptor to always append your data before your AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks for the input

Comment: The $rootScope will be lost on refresh though. The localStorage persists well after the session has expired, unless explicitly cleared.

The sessionStorage is what matches the OP's case most closely.